# Return values for arccosine?

Tags: math, hlsl

I implemented a day/night shader built on the basis that only pixels on the side of an object that is facing the directional light source are illuminated. I calculate this based on the unit vectors between the directional light's position and the position of the pixel in 3D space:

```
float3 direction = normalize(Light.Position - Object.Position);
float theta = abs(acos(dot(normalize(Object.Position), direction))) * 180 / 3.14f;
if (theta < 180)
    color = float3(1.0f);
else
    color = float3(0.2f);

return float4(color, 1.0f);
```

This works well, but since I am brushing up on my math lately, it got me thinking that I should make sure I understand what `acos` is returning.

---

Mathematically, I know that the arccosine should give me an angle in radians from a value between `-1` and `1`, while cosine should give me a value between `-1` and `1` from an angle in radians.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-acos) states that the input value should be between `-1` and `1` for `acos` which follows that idea, but it doesn't tell me if the return value is `0 - π`, `-π - π`, `0 - 2π`, or a similar range.

> ### **Return Value**
>
> The arccosine of the x parameter.
>
> ### Type Description
>
> Name [Template Type] 'Component Type' Size
>   x [scalar, vector, or matrix] 'float' any
>   ret [same as input x] 'float' same dimension(s) as input x

`HLSL` doesn't really give me a way to test this very easily, so I'm wondering if anyone has any documentation on this.

---

What is the return range for the HLSL function `acos`?

Comment: Return value for `acos()` should be in [0,pi], but I cannot point you (at this time) to an authoritative source for HLSL that says so.

Comment: @njuffa Thanks! I was pretty sure that is what was occurring, and I still need a way to test it which could just be passing in values from `System.Math` into a `cbuffer` and see if the values for `0, 1, -1` are the same for the HLSL `acos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through some testing on this topic and have discovered that the HLSL version of `acos` returns a value between `0` and `π`. I proved this to be true with the following:

```
n = 0..3
d = [0, 90, 180, 181]
r = π / 180 * d[n]
c = cos(r)
a = acos(c)
```

The following is the result of the evaluations for `d[n]`:

- `d[0]` returns `a = 0`.
- `d[1]` returns `a = π/2`.
- `d[2]` returns `a = π`.
- `d[3]` returns `a ~= 3.12...`.

This tells us that the return value for `acos` stays true to the [range of usual principle values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) for arccosine:

> 0 ≤ `acos(x)` ≤ π

Also remaining consistent with the definition:

> acos(cos(θ)) = θ

---

I have provided feedback to Microsoft with regards to the lack of detailed documentation on HLSL intrinsic functions in comparison to more common languages.